# How to create a wizard steps with next previous button in admin form same as configurable product's configuration Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, uicomponent

I want to create similar features with next previous button which display while we create a configurable products and select attribute & its combination steps by steps

Answer (score 0):

Try this all steps

Step 1: Create a module

Create the necessary module files in the **app/code** directory. Replace **Vendor** and **Module** with your desired values.

```
   app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php
   app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml
```

Step 2: Create a controller

Create a controller that handles the form submission and navigation between steps. Replace **Vendor** and **Module** with your module values.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/WizardController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class WizardController extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // Handle form submission and navigation logic here
    }
}
```

Step 3: Define routes

Create the **etc/adminhtml/routes.xml** file to define the route for your controller.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="vendor_module" frontName="vendor_module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Step 4: Create a layout file

Create the layout file **vendor_module_wizard.xml** to define the structure and blocks of your form.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_module_wizard.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Wizard" name="vendor_module_wizard" template="Vendor_Module::wizard.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 5: Create form templates

Create template files for each step of your wizard form, such as **step1.phtml, step2.phtml,** etc., inside the **templates** directory.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/step1.phtml**

```
   <!-- Template for Step 1 -->
  <h1>Step 1</h1>
  <!-- Add form fields and content for Step 1 -->
```

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/step2.phtml**

```
    <!-- Template for Step 2 -->
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <!-- Add form fields and content for Step 2 -->
```

Step 6: Define the form block

Define the form block using the appropriate template file for the current step.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Wizard.php**

```
 <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class Wizard extends Template
{
    public function getCurrentStep()
    {
        // Logic to determine the current step
        return 1;
    }

    public function getTemplateFile()
    {
        $currentStep = $this->getCurrentStep();
        return "Vendor_Module::step{$currentStep}.phtml";
    }
}
```

Step 7: Add next and previous buttons

Add next and previous buttons to navigate between steps in your template files.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/wizard.phtml**

```
  <!-- Wizard form template -->
<form method="post" action="<?= $block->getUrl('vendor_module/wizard') ?>">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('form_validation_messages') ?>
    <?= $this->getBlockHtml('vendor_module_wizard') ?>
    <button type="submit" name="back" value="1">Previous</button>
    <button type="submit" name="next" value="1">Next</button>
</form>
```

Step 8: Implement form submission logic

Handle the form submission for each step in your controller.

**File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/WizardController.php**

```
public function execute()
{
    $isBack = (bool)$this->getRequest()->getParam('back');
    $nextStep = $isBack ? $currentStep - 1 : $currentStep + 1;

    // Validate form data and perform necessary actions based on the step

    if ($nextStep <= $totalSteps) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', ['step' => $nextStep]);
        return;
    }

    // Process the final step and redirect to a success page or perform other actions
}
```

Step 9: Store the form data

Store the form data in the session or a temporary storage mechanism as the user progresses through the steps.

Retrieve and use the data when the user reaches the final step or completes the wizard.

Step 10: Finalize the wizard

Once the user completes all the steps, process the final form data according to your requirements.

Perform any necessary actions, such as saving the data to the database or triggering other processes.

```
    HOPE YOU THIS IS USEFUL TO YOU
```